# How can the data taken from the form tag of the first html file and placed in its local storage be output to the second html document?

Tags: javascript, html

Task:

1. Collect data from the form when submitting it;
2. Store this data as an object inside localStorage (don't forget about converting to JSON);
3. Create a second HTML file, in which the list (`ul > li`) outputs all the data that the user entered into the form earlier;
   Question: how to create data output from a script to a second HTML document? How to distinguish between two different HTML files connected to this script?

   ```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="import" href="/intro.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <h1 class="text-center mb-5 mt-5">
                        Please fill in information
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">

                        <form id="form">

                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label class="form-label">Email address</label>
                                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label class="form-label">First name</label>
                                <input name="firstName" type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                <label class="form-label">Last name</label>
                                <input name="lastName" type="email" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                <label class="form-label">Nickname</label>
                                <input name="nickname" type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label class="form-label">Password</label>
                                <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="mb-3 ">
                                <label class="form-label">Select an option</label>
                                <select name="option" class="form-select">
                                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                                    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="mb-3 ">
                                <label class="form-label">Type in your message</label>
                                <textarea
                                        class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Leave a comment here"
                                        style="height: 100px"
                                        name="message"
                                ></textarea>

                            </div>

                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label class="form-label">Default file input example</label>
                                <input name="file" class="form-control" type="file">
                            </div>


                            <div class="mb-3 form-check">
                                <input name="terms" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                                <label class="form-check-label" >Согласен с условиями</label>
                            </div>


                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>


                        </form>



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>



        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>`
   ```

   ```js
       'use strict';

       void function() {
           const formSelector = '#form';
           const submitHandler = (event) => {
               event.preventDefault();

               const inputs = event.target.querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select');
               const data = {};
               
               for(const input of inputs) {
                   data[input.name] = input.value;
               }

               const dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
               localStorage.setItem(formSelector, dataString)
           }

           document
               .querySelector(formSelector)
               .addEventListener('submit', submitHandler)
       }()
   ```

Comment: Well, you'll have to use two different scripts for the two pages. Local Storage will work as long as both pages are on the same website and you use the same Local Storage keys.

Comment: Thank you! What if the files are local (on my computer)?

Comment: You mean the HTML files? If so, you can set up a local server on your computer (`localhost`) and access the files through that (google "localhost server")

Comment: Thank you! Happened. You can make it an answer for me to recognize it as correct.